# Solve the equation $(5-x)^4+(2-x)^4=17$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$(5-x)^4+(2-x)^4=17$$ Initially I was thinking about some sort of a substitution. But if we say $t=(5-x)^4$, then what is $(2-x)^4$ equal to (in terms of $t$)? It is the same if $(2-x)^4=t$.

The only thing I see is to expand the brackets. Is there something clearear?

A fairly simple solution is $x=4$.

Comment: **Hint :** $3$ and $4$ are "obvious" solutions...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, thank you. $4$ was also an obvious solution for me. And how can we use that to solve the problem?

Comment: Divide by $(x-3)(x-4)$ and you are left with a quadratic for the other two solutions.

Comment: @Andrei, how can I divide the equation by $(x-3)(x-4)$ when it's in this form: $$(5-x)^4+(2-x)^4=17?$$ Should I expand the brackets?

Comment: Yes. It should be a polynomial of order $4$

Comment: You can search for a,b,c such that  $(5-x)^4+(2-x)^4-17=(x - 3)(x - 4)(ax^2+bx+c)$ by giving some values to x (0, 2, 5)

Comment: Maybe you can somehow use that by fourth powers of real numbers being $\ge 0$, all *real* solutions have to lie in $(2-\sqrt[4]{17}, 2+\sqrt[4]{17}) \cap (5-\sqrt[4]{17}, 5+\sqrt[4]{17}) = (5-\sqrt[4]{17}, 2+\sqrt[4]{17}) \approx (2.9604, 4.0305)$.

Answer (score 4):

If you substitute $x= t+7/2$ the equation reduces to

$$2t^4+27t^2+ \frac{81}{8} = 17$$

which is quadratic in $t^2$.

The two ``obvious" solutions are equivalent to $t=1/2$ and $t=-1/2$ so you can factor the polynomial pretty quickly if you don't want to use quadratic formula.

(You get the $7/2$ by averaging $5$ and $2$.)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I didn't get what I can try to substitute. Isn't it $t=x-\dfrac{7}{2}$? You reduce the equation by expanding, right?

Comment: When you make the substitution, the two binomials are conjugate.  I used Pascals triangle to expand them both. The odd degree terms cancel.  (That's why I went for the symmetric version.)

Answer (score 2):

I used hints in the comments to factorize the polynomial.

We know $x = 3$ or $x = 4$.

That is,
$$
p(x) = (5-x)^4 + (2-x)^4 - 17 = 2(x-3)(x-4)(x-a)(x-b)
$$

Where the factor $2$ is given by $x^4 + x^4$. To find $a$ and $b$, I put $x = 0$ and $x= 1$.

1. $x = 0$ gives $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 ab = 5^4 - 1^4 = (5^2 + 1)(5^2 - 1) = 26\cdot 24$. We have $ab = 26$.
2. $x = 1$ gives $2\cdot 2 \cdot 3(1-a)(1-b) = 4^4 - 2^4 = (4^2 + 2^2)(4^2 - 2^2) = 240$. Therefore, $(1 - a)(1 - b) = 1 - a - b + ab = 20$, which gives $a + b = 7$.

So the resulting factorization is
$$
p(x) = 2(x-3)(x-4)(x^2 - 7x + 26)
$$

By solving $x^2 - 7x + 26 = 0$, we can find the remaining roots. I will leave it to you to find the roots, but it is obvious that they are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

After expansion, the rational root theorem and the quadratic formula may be used to solve the equation.

$$
(5-x)^4+(2-x)^4=17\\
2 x^4 - 28 x^3 + 174 x^2 - 532 x + 624 = 0\\
\text{the factors of 624 are }\\ 
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 24, 26, 39, 48, 52, 78, 104, 156, 208, 312, 624}\\
2 (x - 3) (x - 4) (x^2 - 7 x + 26)=0\\
x=3,\space x=4,\space x = \frac{7\pm i\sqrt{(55)}}{/2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$(5−x)^4+(2−x)^4=17$

Opening the brackets

$2x^4−28x^3+174x^2−532x+641=17$ which is equal to

$2x^4−28x^3+174x^2−532x+624=0$

By hit and trial we factor the LHS side of the equation

$2(x−3)(x−4)(x^2−7x+26)=0$

Setting factors equal to zero

$x=3$

$x=4$

Determinant of $x^2-7x+26 = 55$ which is less than zero so this has no real roots

So $x = 3,4.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).